# swift Xcode Secure Text Entry Asterisk not show when Screen Mirroring / Recording

Tags: swift, xcode, frontend, passwords, mirroring

I have checked the Secure Text Entry and entered
"pwdTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true"
as the code.
Therefore, I can see the asterisk well inside password text field of my app.

However, just by mirroring the screen or recording the screen, it only becomes white and the asterisk is invisible.
Is there anyone who knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is powerful of UITextField with secure field enable provided by Apple.
It hides data for screenshots and video records to preventing sensitive data leakage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
Then is there any way to make a similar effect by bypassing without using SecureTextEntry? I would really appreciate it if you could give me any suggestions for reference.

Comment: If you don't want to use text field with isSecureTextEntry, I think you can custom the textfield by yourself. But you need to handle the behavior like textfield with secure entry. However, I still recommend you to use textfield with secure entry provided by Apple. Because I'm not sure Apple can reject your app or not while you submit your app to Apple for reviewing with custom textfield like secure field.